# Pygame bullet vectors adding together unintentionally when firing multiple at once

Tags: python, pygame

I have been working on a game of mine to pass the time while stuck at home. Early on in development I added the ability to fire bullets, and it worked great. Now I have added some extra functionality and whenever I try to fire more than one bullet at a time all the bullets act extremely weirdly.

I have looked through SO a fair amount and I haven't seen anything resembling my issue.

Steps to reproduce:

- Click mouse button to fire once
- Before the bullet hits the edge of the screen, move the mouse and fire again
- (You can click as many times as you want and the issue will compound)

Results:

- The original bullet 'disappears' and a new bullet is created at the source, but:

  - The direction is halfway between the two clicks, and
  - The speed of the bullet is either much faster or much slower than the first, depending on the second click

I say 'disappear' because the bullet never actually disappears, I think it just gets stacked on top of the other one. I say this because the number of sprites in the `world.bullets` group is the correct number.

I believe that the issue has to do with either the `Slingshot()` or the `Bullet()` class.

I have added a runnable example below:

```
import pygame as pyg
import random
import math
import os

os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED'] = '1'

FPS = 30


class Player(pyg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, window, world):
        super().__init__()
        self.window = window
        self.world = world

        self.image = pyg.Surface((30, 30))
        self.image.fill((0, 0, 255))

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.draw_rect = self.rect

        self.vel = pyg.Vector2((0, 0))
        self.speed = 12

        self.cur_weapon = Slingshot(window, world)

    def move_x(self, amount):
        self.rect.x += int(amount)

         # Edges of the screen
        if self.rect.right > self.world.rect.width:
            self.rect.right = self.world.rect.width
            self.vel.x = 0
        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0
            self.vel.x = 0

    def move_y(self, amount):
        self.rect.y += int(amount)

         # Edges of the screen
        if self.rect.top < 0:
            self.rect.top = 0
            self.vel.y = 0
        if self.rect.bottom > self.world.rect.height:
            self.rect.bottom = self.world.rect.height
            self.vel.y = 0

    def fire(self):
        bullet = self.cur_weapon.new_bullet()
        self.world.bullets.add(bullet)
        self.cur_weapon.fire()

    def update(self):
        self.move_x(self.vel.x)
        self.move_y(self.vel.y)

        self.vel.x *= .3
        if abs(self.vel.x) < .2: self.vel.x = 0
        self.vel.y *= .3
        if abs(self.vel.y) < .2: self.vel.y = 0

        self.cur_weapon.set_pos(self.draw_rect)

    def render(self):
        self.window.blit(self.image, self.draw_rect)

        self.cur_weapon.render()

class Slingshot():
    def __init__(self, window, world):
        self.window = window
        self.world = world

        self.image = pyg.Surface((30, 20)).convert_alpha()
        self.image.fill((0, 0, 50))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.image_source = self.image

        self.b_image = pyg.Surface((10, 10))
        self.b_image.fill((200, 200, 200))
        self.b_rect = self.b_image.get_rect()

        self.bullet_data = {'image': self.b_image,
                            'rect': self.b_rect,
                            'owner': 'player',
                            'source': self.rect.center,
                            'target': camera.get_world_pos(pyg.mouse.get_pos()),
                            'speed': 40,
                            'invulnerable': False,
                            'bouncy': False}

    def new_bullet(self):
        self.bullet_data['source'] = self.rect.center
        self.bullet_data['target'] = camera.get_world_pos(pyg.mouse.get_pos())

        bullet = Bullet(self.window, self.world, self.bullet_data)

        return bullet

    def fire(self):
        ...

    def set_pos(self, p_rect):
        m_pos = pyg.mouse.get_pos()

        dir = math.atan2((m_pos[1] - p_rect.centery), (m_pos[0] - p_rect.centerx))
        x = math.cos(dir)
        y = math.sin(dir)

        self.rect.center = p_rect.center
        self.rect.move_ip((x * 30, y * 30))

        self.image = pyg.transform.rotate(self.image_source, math.degrees(-dir))

    def render(self):
        self.window.blit(self.image, self.rect)


class Bullet(pyg.sprite.Sprite):
    """
         XXXXXXXXXXXX
         XXXX      XXXX
         XXXX      XXXX
         XXXXXXXXXXX
         XXXX      XXXX
         XXXX      XXXX
         XXXXXXXXXXXX

    Minimap label
    """
    def __init__(self, window, world, data):
        super().__init__()
        self.window = window
        self.world = world

        self.data = data

        self.image = self.data['image']
        self.rect = self.data['rect']
        self.rect.center = camera.get_world_pos(self.data['source'])
        self.draw_rect = self.rect

        self.speed = self.data['speed']
        target = self.data['target']
        dir = math.atan2((target[1] - self.rect.centery), (target[0] - self.rect.centerx))
        # A number in the range (-1, 1), multiplied by speed to move each tick
        self.x = math.cos(dir)
        self.y = math.sin(dir)

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += int(self.x * self.speed)
        self.rect.y += int(self.y * self.speed)

         # Edges of the screen
        if self.rect.right > self.world.rect.width:
            self.kill()
        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.kill()
        if self.rect.top < 0:
            self.kill()
        if self.rect.bottom > self.world.rect.height:
            self.kill()

    def render(self):
        self.window.blit(self.image, self.draw_rect)

class Camera():
    """
            XXXXXXXXX
         XXXX       XXXX
         XXXX
         XXXX
         XXXX
         XXXX       XXXX
            XXXXXXXXX

    Minimap label
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.rect = pyg.rect.Rect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT)

    def get_world_pos(self, pos):
        return (pos[0] - self.rect.left, pos[1] - self.rect.top)

    def apply_lens(self, player, world):
        player.draw_rect = player.rect.move(self.rect.topleft)

        everything = (world.statics.sprites() +
                      world.bullets.sprites())

        for sprite in everything:
            sprite.draw_rect = sprite.rect.move(self.rect.topleft)

    def follow(self, sprite):
        pos = sprite.rect.center

         # Subtract half of the screen to center the sprite
        top = pos[0] - WIDTH//2
        left = pos[1] - HEIGHT//2
        width = self.rect.width
        height = self.rect.height

        self.rect = pyg.rect.Rect(-top, -left, width, height)


class World():
    """
        XXX         XXX
        XXX         XXX
        XXX   XXX   XXX
        XXX  XXXXX  XXX
        XXX XXX XXX XXX
        XXXXX     XXXXX
        XXX         XXX

    Minimap label
    """
    def __init__(self, window):
        self.window = window
        self.rooms = []
        self.statics = pyg.sprite.Group()
        self.bullets = pyg.sprite.Group()

        self.rooms = []
        self.statics.empty()
        self.bullets.empty()

        self.image = pyg.Surface((1000, 750))
        self.image.fill((150, 150, 150))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.draw_rect = self.rect
        self.statics.add(StaticObject(self.window, self.rect.center, self.rect.size))
        self.statics.add(StaticObject(self.window, self.rect.center, (50, 50)))


class StaticObject(pyg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, window, pos, size):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pyg.Surface(size)
        self.image.fill((random.randint(0, 255), random.randint(0, 255), random.randint(0, 255)))
        self.window = window
        self.window_rect = window.get_rect()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = pos
        self.draw_rect = self.rect

    def render(self):
        if self.draw_rect.colliderect(self.window_rect):
            self.window.blit(self.image, self.draw_rect)


def terminate():
    pyg.quit()
    raise SystemExit()

    """
        XXX         XXX
        XXXXX     XXXXX
        XXX XXX XXX XXX
        XXX  XXXXX  XXX
        XXX   XXX   XXX
        XXX         XXX
        XXX         XXX

    Minimap label
    """
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pyg.init()
    pyg.display.set_caption("Reversal")
    window = pyg.display.set_mode((1000, 700))
    WIDTH, HEIGHT = pyg.display.get_window_size()
    camera = Camera()
    world = World(window)

    player = Player(window, world)
    player.rect.center = world.rect.center

    clock = pyg.time.Clock()

    while True:
        for event in pyg.event.get():
            if event.type == pyg.QUIT:
                terminate()
            elif event.type == pyg.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pyg.K_ESCAPE:
                    terminate()
            elif event.type == pyg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if event.button == 1:
                    player.fire()

        event_keys = pyg.key.get_pressed()
        if event_keys[pyg.K_LEFT] or event_keys[pyg.K_a]:
            player.vel.x -= player.speed
        if event_keys[pyg.K_RIGHT] or event_keys[pyg.K_d]:
            player.vel.x += player.speed
        if event_keys[pyg.K_UP] or event_keys[pyg.K_w]:
            player.vel.y -= player.speed
        if event_keys[pyg.K_DOWN] or event_keys[pyg.K_s]:
            player.vel.y += player.speed

        camera.follow(player)
        camera.apply_lens(player, world)

        window.fill((255, 255, 255))

        for s in world.statics:
            s.render()

        for b in world.bullets:
            b.update()
            b.render()

        player.update()
        player.render()

        pyg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(FPS)
```

Thanks for any help you could provide.

Comment: Code is way too long to be considered a [mre]... Please take the [tour] and see [ask].

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Comment: We expect you to perform basic diagnosis to include with your post.  At the very least, print the suspected values at the point of error and trace them back to their sources.  Don't merely *narrate* the problem, but supply the specific metrics: what objects are where?

Comment: Also, please don't expect us to enter test data.  Your MRE should provide the input, not our clicks or typing.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your `Bullet` objects share the same `pygame.Rect` object. The instruction `self.rect = self.data ['rect']` does not create a new `pygame.Rect` object. It just stores a reference to `self.data['rect']` to the attribute `self.rect`.

Use the [`copy`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.copy) method to create a copy of the bullet start rectangle when a new bullet is fired:

<s>`self.rect = self.data['rect']`</s>

```py
self.rect = self.data['rect'].copy()
```

Comment: Wow that was simple. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found it:
In `Slingshot`:

```
    def new_bullet(self):
        self.bullet_data['source'] = self.rect.center
        self.bullet_data['target'] = camera.get_world_pos(pyg.mouse.get_pos())

        bullet = Bullet(self.window, self.world, self.bullet_data)

        return bullet
```

You create a new `Bullet` and give it a reference to this `Slingshot`'s `bullet_data`. When changing that `bullet_data`, as you do every time `new_bullet` is called, all `Bullet`s fired by this `Slingshot` will have that data changed. I think you want to clone `Slingshot`'s `self.bullet_data` into a new dict, change that new dict's `source` and `target`, and pass THAT into the `Bullet()` constructor.

Something more like

```
    def new_bullet(self):
        new_bullet_data = {}
        for key, value in self.bullet_data.items():
            new_bullet_data[key] = value
        new_bullet_data['source'] = self.rect.center
        new_bullet_data['target'] = camera.get_world_pos(pyg.mouse.get_pos())

        bullet = Bullet(self.window, self.world, new_bullet_data)

        return bullet
```

Comment: That's very helpful thanks.